# Pandas get row number where value error occurs

Tags: python, pandas, django-rest-framework

For like I have a df

```
name | point | age|
-------------------
Jon  | 20    | 26 |
Mike | abc   | 20 |
```

so I need to check if the point is int if not then I need to point out in which row and which column the Invalid data type is given

I need output like:
`Column 2, row 2`

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output for clarity?

Comment: Do you really want "Column 2, row 2" or is `(1, 'point')` OK?

Comment: @mozway I need the column name or number and the row number

Comment: My approach gives you the column name and the number in python numbering if you have a range index (if not first run `.reset_index(drop=True)`). I added an extra approach in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to identify all non-numeric cells:

```
m = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isna()

out = m.where(m).stack().index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[(0, 'name'), (1, 'name'), (1, 'point')]
```

If you only want to identify invalid data in columns in which some values are numeric but not all:

```
m = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isna()
out = df.loc[:, ~m.all()].where(m).stack().index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'point')]
```

Finally, if you already have NaNs in the input and want to ignore those, use:

```
m = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isna() & df.notna()
out = df.loc[:, ~m.all()].where(m).stack().index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'point')]
```

Used input:

```
   name point   age
0   Jon    20   NaN
1  Mike   abc  20.0
```

If you need row/column numbers starting from 1:

```
tmp = df.set_axis(range(1, df.shape[0]+1)).set_axis(range(1, df.shape[1]+1), axis=1)

m = tmp.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isna()
out = tmp.loc[:, ~m.all()].where(m).stack().index.tolist()

print(out)
# [(2, 2)]
```